Need A Filter Like Function In Excel That Can Behave Like XLOOKUP But Still Spill Multiple Answers
I am trying to improve the functionality of a large workbook I made with hundreds of sheets used for scheduling a housing project. It does an excellent job using query tables and XLOOKUP INDIRECT functions to organize the individual task information onto their own sheets.
My goal is to further break down a table of tasks for my labourer's into a daily list. So instead of having a large confusing spreadsheet to look at that has everything and find todays date, the information would automatically be listed on a printable page of which task needs to be performed in a particular unit on a particular day. My idea for this was to use the filter function to browse individual columns in the Labourer Sched Table (the tasks, columns B through M) and return which row has a matching date (The Lot Number from Column A), and return this information on the Labour List sheet.. It has to only look at one column though because the possibility of a repeated date being in another column giving me a false return exists, so I can't just treat the whole table as an array.
The rub for this issue is that FILTER itself doesn't seem to handle non-adjacent columns as one would expect, as well I can't figure out if it's possible to make it look at only one column at a time while looking for its target. It's very possible I'm barking up the wrong tree, but my other possible option XLOOKUP stops after it finds the first result and it will possible to have up to 10 returns.
So basically what I think I need is a workaround that will behave like XLOOKUP but still spill all the applicable data like FILTER.
FILTER works well pulling data from a smaller table (Closing List), but as soon as my tables get larger I start getting Value Errors
Another thought I had is that the currently unscheduled units give value errors because they have no schedule data entered yet (I just use the table filters to hide them normally). Could these currently unused Value Error cells be causing the issue, and is there a way to trap the filter function to omit them?
I've been beating my head against this for a couple of days now and am at a loss. Images Attached for clarity.
New Labour List Tab With Working FILTER for closings, 
Closing List Tab, 
Labour List tab with filter function for first task, 
Labour Sched Tab with no table formatting, 
Labour Sched Tab With Formatting and Function Box.
EDIT:
Upon some more digging, it is the value errors in the include array causing the issues. Is there any elegant way to have errors in you include array and have the filter function ignore them?
